# How to restart RabbitMQ service

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-services

I am getting a strange error while restarting the rabbitmq service and because of that I am unable to restart RabbitMQ service. I got this message from EventViewer and have tried to find solution by googling but no luck..please suggest.

> RabbitMQ: Erlang machine voluntarily stopped. The service is not
>   restarted as OnFail is set to ignore.

Thanks

Answer (score 131):

On a modern Linux you can restart it like any other service

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server restart
```

There is a specific control interface as well

```
sudo rabbitmqctl "report"
sudo rabbitmqctl "reset"
```

Comment: Oh, I see you have a windows tag, didn't notice that.

Comment: Funny thing here is: The question has a windows tag, but this answer 10 upvotes, 10 upvotes directly to Linux :D

Comment: People dont see it's for windows question as I didn't. But it's resolving linux users problems ehehehe

Answer (score 34):

As per the documentation of [RabbitMQ CLI docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html) you can do the following:

```
rabbitmqctl stop
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Answer (score 13):

Since none of the answers actually answer the question, in command prompt, type:

```
net stop rabbitmq
net start rabbitmq
```

Comment: Yeah, that answers the question. Worked for me on Win7

Answer (score 11):

If you reinstall RabbitMQ and have issues running it as a windows service, a workaround could be the following:

In cmd.exe, run from the rabbit sbin folder:

```
rabbitmq-service.bat remove
rabbitmq-service.bat install
net start rabbitmq
```

It worked for me on windows 7.

Answer (score 6):

in Your installed server first run stop command

```
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.8\sbin>rabbitmqctl.bat stop
```

Then start command:

```
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.8\sbin>rabbitmqctl.bat start_app
```

Or via GUI windows service : right click and then click on restart :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

in my case helped start by direct call

```
sudo  /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a windows machine and RabitMQ is installed in the machine, then got to **C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-\sbin>**

and run the following command

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl force_reset
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

And it will look like this

```
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.9.5\sbin>rabbitmqctl stop_app
Stopping rabbit application on node rabbit@DESKTOP-MQS...

C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.9.5\sbin>rabbitmqctl force_reset
Forcefully resetting node rabbit@DESKTOP-MQS...

C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.9.5\sbin>rabbitmqctl start_app
Starting node rabbit@DESKTOP-MQS...

C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.9.5\sbin>
```

Answer (score 0):

First go to `C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.6\sbin` then run command prompt as `administrator` and run `rabbitmq-server restart`

Make sure to go to the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried various options in server. Finally it resolved.

1. Install Erlang version at first as a Administrator
2. Install RabbitMQ version as a Administrator
3. Delete db file in the RabbitMQ installation folder

Still issues persists, check the environment variables for RabbitMQ and Erlang

Hope this will help!.